# How to create a 5D tensor as the input of a 3DCNN with tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I try to create a 4D tensor as input of a 2DCNN. I am confused about how to create a 5DCNN .Is the 4D tensor as one of dimension of a 5D tensor? Is there someone who know the detials ?

Comment: You may want to look at https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/ and search for 5D

Comment: thanks ！ do you have some idea about it?

Comment: I haven't had a need but here is what they put for input: Input shape

5D tensor with shape: (samples, depth, first_axis_to_pad, second_axis_to_pad, third_axis_to_pad)